# $http post silent no results if image is included in the body

Tags: angularjs, node.js

If I add image to the post request, then no answer either on the client side or the server side.

```
    var self = this;
    var path = "/admin/speakers";
    var segment = "";
    var body = token.body;
    var config = {
        withCredentials: true,
        headers: {
            'x-auth-token': localStorage.getItem("model.LoginProxy.authToken"),
            'Content-Type': undefined
        },
        transformRequest: angular.identity
    };

    this.$http.post(path + segment, body, config)
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            self.onResult({data: data, status: status, headers: headers, config: config});
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            self.onFault({data: data, status: status, headers: headers, config: config});
        });
```

part of the code that deals with the image upload with some form data.

```
formData.append("bio", this.$scope.data.bio);
formData.append("photo", document.getElementById("photo").files[0]);
```

On the server side, I do get this output.

```
{ fieldname: 'photo',
  originalname: '02.jpg',
  name: 'd8a96dffc1ae80515a94fdb159ab3b9e.jpg',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
  path: '/var/folders/jg/hkmz0fdn64g8w1jgf60j2lcw0000gn/T/d8a96dffc1ae80515a94fdb159ab3b9e.jpg',
  extension: 'jpg',
  size: 10306,
  truncated: false,
  buffer: null }
```

Found the actual Issue but need help on this for resolution.

html + angular

```
<input type="hidden" name="bucket" value="photos" ng-model="data.bucket" />

formData.append("bucket", this.$scope.data.bucket);
```

the bucket is ending up `undefined` on the server, It's a hidden field on the form, wondering how do we set these values, I didn't wanna hardcode the bucket name in `$scope` but rather pick the value from the form itself. How is it done in angular + html?

Expectation/Question

I expect `value="photos" ng-model="data.bucket"` to bind to `$scope.data.bucket` but it's ending up undefined on the $scope, is there a way without hardcoding folder upload name in `$scope.data` ?

Comment: what is the question exactly? You seem to be asking something about an image not being processed, but I fail to see any image mentioned in the code provided.

Comment: I still fail to see the question here.  Your edit now shows that you received the image at the server, but not what you are trying to do with it, or really what problem you are having at all.

Comment: I found the issue now but I still need help on this, I'm passing upload directory name to the server, it's ending up undefined, I'm going to add more details to my question

Comment: I know you are really trying to explain your problem, but you're still not there.  what is `bucket`? what do you mean "pick the value from the form", if the input is hidden? is `data.bucket` empty in the controller before the form is submitted?

Comment: also, something doesn't seem right with your code here; You are only showing snippets of code, not full functions, but with Angular 2 way binding, you should rarely if ever have to use `document.getElementById`;  I suspect that your function that does the submission is more JQuery like than Angular like.

Comment: bucket is like a folder name, (AWS s3 buckets), and you're right, the issue is data.bucket is ending up undefined on the client side in `$scope`, I expect `ng-model=data.bucket` to pick the input text value that I've hardcoded as "photos" in my html form, but it's nulling it out

Comment: right, you can't use `value=` and `ng-model=` in the same element.  `ng-model=` sets the `value` to whatever exists in the controller.  If `data.bucket` is `null` in the controller, than `value` will be set to null as well.  it doesn't parse `value` and store it into `ng-model`....

Comment: right, how can I force `$scope.data.bucket` to take the value from `<input` instead of hardcoding it as `$scope.data.bucket = 'photos'` in my code.

Comment: you will likely have to define a getterSetter for the field, similar to what is demonstrated in the official angular documentation for ngModel.  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel#!/

Comment: I saw the example, it's like you're still hardcoding the value in controller, the snippet from the page `$scope.example = {
        text: 'guest',
        word: /^\s*\w*\s*$/
      }`

Comment: do you even need `ng-model` at all if your client side isn't using the value?  if you left off `ng-model`, that `value=` should be present intact in the form submission....